# Removing element from DOM after set amount of time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out the React way to remove an element from the DOM after an event if fired.

I am attempting to flash an alert (`copySuccess`) when `onClick={this.props.handleCopyFact}` is fired, and then fade that alert out after 5 seconds. The state of each of these are set within a parent component.

Here is the code for my component:

```js
module.exports = React.createClass({

render: function() {

var copy = null;
if (!this.props.copying && !this.props.editting) {
  copy = (
    <div className="copy-fact-container" onClick={this.props.handleCopyFact}>
      <i className="icon-copy"></i>
      <span>Copy</span>
    </div>
    );

}

var copySuccess = null;
if (this.props.copySuccess) {
  copySuccess = (
    <div className="copy-success">
      <div><i className="icon icon-clipboard"></i></div>
      <p className="heading">Copied to Clipboard</p>
    </div>
    );
}

return (
  <div className="row-body"
    onMouseEnter={this.props.toggleCopyFact}
    onMouseLeave={this.props.toggleCopyFact}>
    <MDEditor editting={this.props.editting}
      content={this.props.content}
      changeContent={this.props.changeContent}/>
  {copy}
  {copySuccess}
  </div>
);
}
});
```

Comment: I was also advised by Pete Hunt to check out React-bootstrap's overlay trigger component so see how to show/hide elements. https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/OverlayTrigger.js

Answer (score 45, accepted):

One way is to create an Expire component which will hide its children after a delay.  You can use this in conjunction with a CSSTransitionGroup to do the fade out behavior.

### [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zomiloma/3/edit?js,output)

Usage:

```js
render: function(){
    return <Expire delay={5000}>This is an alert</Expire>
}
```

The component:

```js
var Expire = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {delay: 1000};
  },
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {visible: true};
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    // reset the timer if children are changed
    if (nextProps.children !== this.props.children) {
      this.setTimer();
      this.setState({visible: true});
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
      this.setTimer();
  },
  setTimer: function() {
    // clear any existing timer
    this._timer != null ? clearTimeout(this._timer) : null;

    // hide after `delay` milliseconds
    this._timer = setTimeout(function(){
      this.setState({visible: false});
      this._timer = null;
    }.bind(this), this.props.delay);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    clearTimeout(this._timer);
  },
  render: function() {
    return this.state.visible 
           ? <div>{this.props.children}</div>
           : <span />;
  }
});
```

Comment: Would you just wrap the Expire component in the CSSTransitionGroup and then use `.example-enter` in my css to control the transitions?

Comment: You'd wrap the content of the Expire component.  `<Expire><ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example">stuff</ReactCSSTransitionGroup></Expire>`

Comment: I tried using this component and wrapping ReactCSSTransitionGroup as described here, but it seems the CSS transition classes are not being added to the Expire component's children.

Comment: Might consider checking to see if the component is still mounted before setting `visible` to `false`. If the component has been destroyed by some navigation or other function, you'll get a warning. `if(this.isMounted()){ this.setState({visible:false}); }`

Comment: [isMounted is deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html), but yes, it should be clearing the timer.

Comment: But that just results in the ReactCSSTransitionGroup element disappearing after the delay, without animating out. How do you make it animate before disappearing? (The relevant CSS transitions have been added, but the wrapped element just disappears abruptly). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you really compare (object) props like `nextProps.children !== this.props.children`?

Answer (score 26):

Furthermore simplified way using **Hooks**.

From [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) docs,

> `useEffect` hook combinely does all these three `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and
> `componentWillUnmount`

Your `Expire` component should be

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Expire = props => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setVisible(false);
    }, props.delay);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer)
  }, [props.delay]);

  return visible ? <div>{props.children}</div> : <div />;
};

export default Expire;
```

Now, pass the `delay` prop in `Expire` component.

```
<Expire delay="5000">Hooks are awesome!</Expire>
```

I created a working example using [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hide-element-from-dom-react-way-44g3n?from-embed)

Comment: Why ```useEffect``` doesn't have a second ```[]``` argument? The effect only should run one time

Comment: Didn't realize until you mentioned it. Saw that the `useEffect` as calling twice when the element hides. After adding the second argument, it doesn't. I corrected my code @SaberHayati

Comment: You had forgotten to return a cleanup method in the useEffect hook.

Answer (score 15):

Updated @FakeRainBrigand 's answer to support a more modern React syntax that uses a class in lieu of the deprecated `React.createComponent` method.

```
class Expire extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {visible:true}
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // reset the timer if children are changed
    if (nextProps.children !== this.props.children) {
      this.setTimer();
      this.setState({visible: true});
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setTimer();
  }

  setTimer() {
    // clear any existing timer
    if (this._timer != null) {
      clearTimeout(this._timer)
    }

    // hide after `delay` milliseconds
    this._timer = setTimeout(function(){
      this.setState({visible: false});
      this._timer = null;
    }.bind(this), this.props.delay);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this._timer);
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.visible
      ? <div>{this.props.children}</div>
      : <span />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated @pyRabbit to use the newer React hooks and a prop field to toggle the visibility of a `children` component:

```
const DelayedToggle = ({ children, delay, show }) => {
  let timer = null;

  // First, set the internal `visible` state to negate 
  // the provided `show` prop
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(!show);

  // Call `setTimer` every time `show` changes, which is
  // controlled by the parent.
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimer();
  }, [show]);

  function setTimer() {
    // clear any existing timer
    if (timer != null) {
      clearTimeout(timer)
    }

    // hide after `delay` milliseconds
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setVisible(!visible);
      timer = null;
    }, delay);
  }

  // Here use a `Fade` component from Material UI library
  // to create a fade-in and -out effect.
  return visible 
    ?
    <Fade in={show} timeout={{
      enter: delay + 50,
      exit: delay - 50,
    }}
    >
      {children}
    </Fade>
    : <span />;
};

const Parent = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>toggle</button>
      <DelayedToggle 
        delay={300} 
        show={show}
        children={<div><h1>Hello</h1></div>}
      />
    </>
  )
};
```

[image: Edit peaceful-galileo-hvqb5]